# On the convergence of metric spaces

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, metric-spaces, riemannian-geometry

Suppose $(X_n,d_n) \rightarrow (X_{\infty}, d_{\infty})$ in the Gromov-Hausdorff sense. Is there a compact (or locally compact) space $Z$ such that (almost all) the $X_i$ embed isometrically into $Z$ and and $d_H(X_n, X_\infty) \rightarrow 0$ where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff distance in $Z$.

If not, is this true when $X_n$ is a smooth manifold, and $d_n$ is a distance inducing the topology (if not, then $d_n$ a Riemannian distance)?

Comment: First, one has to assume all $X_n$ are compact - otherwise one can let all $X_n=X$, where $X$ is an uncountable set with $d(x, x')=1$ whenever $x\neq x'$ in $X$, and this cannot be isometrically embedded into a compact space. Now if all $X_n$ and $X_\infty$ are compact, one can embed a subsequence $X_{n_i}$ together with $X_\infty$ isometrically into a compact space $Z$ and $d_H(X_{n_i}, X_\infty)\to 0$. I am not sure how to (or if it is possible) do the whole sequence.

Comment: Can you provide some source or argument for this claim? Just saying it is true is not particularly helpful.